# "stop over" vs. "stop off" vs. "lay over" in AmEng vernacular

Tags: american-english, word-usage, vernacular, dialects

What's the difference between those terms? Can they be used just about interchangeably?

***stopover*** *n.*/***stop over*** *v.*

> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stop-off)
>
> *noun* A brief stop in the course of a journey, as to eat, sleep, or visit friends.
>
> *verb* To make a stopover

***layover*** *n.*/***lay over*** *v.*

> [FDO](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/layover)
>
> *noun* A brief stay in the course of a journey
>
> *verb* To pause some place during one's journey

Please, compare:

> *There's a **stop-off** to change planes in Chicago*.
>
> *There's a **stopover** to change planes in Chicago*.
>
> *There's a **layover** to change planes in Chicago.*

-and-

> *On our way to New York, we **stopped over** in Philadelphia for the night*.
>
> *On our way to New York, we **stopped off** in Philadelphia for the night*.
>
> *On our way to New York, we **laid over** in Philadelphia for the night*.

-and-

> *Marj decided to **stop over** in Pittsburg to see an old friend*.
>
> *Marj decided to **stop off** in Pittsburg to see an old friend*.
>
> *Marj decided to **lay over** in Pittsburg to see an old friend*.

Comment: Note that there is a technical distinction between a *stopover* and a *layover* in travel, but that distinction is not respected by the lay person (much as *direct* vs. *nonstop*), and the distinction is not always consistent even within the industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on who is speaking and to whom the statement is addressed, the phrases are generally interchangeable **in that they will be generally understood by a US native English-speaking interlocutor.**

That said, to the aforementioned native English-speaking interloctor's ear (i.e., *mine*) the term ***lay over (v.), & layover (n.)*** expresses a connotation that the pause in the journey is dictated by circumstances, e.g. an airline schedule, a travel agent's whim, or a typhoon-blizzard.

If I have a **layover** in Newark, I envision a night in a Motel 6 near EWR if I'm lucky, or if I'm not, fitful dozing on vinyl seats designed by Torquemada.

If I **stop off** in Louisville, it's intentional, not a quirk of fate. I may look forward to meeting friends for drinks at the Seelbach Hotel before heading up the street to watch the Bats play baseball.

*If I **stop over** anywhere, it's a local call. I will be around the corner at Dave and Meghan's, for beer and bratwurst after a hard week at the word factory.*

(Remember, these are idiosyncratic distinctions from my corner of the US, my generation, and my sense of language.  Opinions of British cousins, travel agents, and visitors from Rumtifoo may differ.)